# pyshp Attribute error: 'module' object has no attribute 'Writer'

Tags: python, attributes, shapefile, attributeerror

I am trying to create a shapefile using pyshp on a windows machine. I have a long set of coordinates that I pan to use but step one is getting this small set to work.

```
import shapefile as sf

w=sf.Writer(sf.POINT)
w.point(30.1,30)
w.point(50.1,30)
w.point(70.1,30)
w.point(90,1,30)
w.field('LAT')
w.field('LONG','C','40')
w.record('First','Point')
w.record('Second','Point')
w.record('Third','Point')
w.record('Fourth','Point')
w.save('testpoints')
```

I keep getting this error:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Writer'

I am choosing the Writer attribute from the built in drop down bar after typing 'sf.' so I know shapefile does have this attribute.  It is specifically 'Writer' and not 'writer'.

Is anyone familiar with pyshp?

Comment: Did you name any of your modules of packages `shapefile` or similar?

Comment: Please post your full traceback